# Unity Android: Error while generating the main dex list

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-multidex

I have upgraded my Google Play Services to 0.9.53 and I have not been successful with my builds with both Unity 2017.4.27f1 and Android Studio 3.4.1.

I have tried a lot of methods but I can't seem to find a solution. Using Android Studio, I received two more specific errors.

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.compat.BuildConfig

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.compat.BuildConfig
```

This is my Gradle mainTemplate file and the error from Unity.

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://repository.adincube.com/maven'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://ogury.bintray.com/sdk-android'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.adincube.sdk:AdinCube-Unity-3626ebe:2.7.8@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"

**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**
    }

**SIGN**
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            **SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }
**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}


**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
]
stdout[
:checkReleaseClasspath
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:checkReleaseManifest
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseManifest
:unity-android-resources:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:unity-android-resources:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:unity-android-resources:checkReleaseManifest
:unity-android-resources:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResValues
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseResources
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseRenderscript
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResValues
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResources
:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseRFile
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseRFile
:processReleaseResources
C:\Users\Sogon\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appnext-sdk-2.3.1.471-3.aar\2216ff231c2f864954d26d3c95094ac3\res\drawable\apnxt_ads_rating_bar.xml:3: warn: generated id 'android:id/background' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Sogon\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appnext-sdk-2.3.1.471-3.aar\2216ff231c2f864954d26d3c95094ac3\res\drawable\apnxt_ads_rating_bar.xml:7: warn: generated id 'android:id/progress' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Sogon\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appnext-sdk-2.3.1.471-3.aar\2216ff231c2f864954d26d3c95094ac3\res\drawable\apnxt_ads_rating_bar.xml:5: warn: generated id 'android:id/secondaryProgress' for external package 'android'.

:generateReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:unity-android-resources:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseSources
:unity-android-resources:javaPreCompileRelease
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:unity-android-resources:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:unity-android-resources:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseShaders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseShaders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseAssets
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseAssets
:unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseShaders
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseShaders
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseAssets
:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease FAILED
49 actionable tasks: 37 executed, 12 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by a iuild setup issue. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes, and go through the dependencies to see which include the class `android.support.compat.BuildConfig`.

Comment: did you fix this? i'm having the same problem